# how to change attribute value dynamically in json file?

Tags: json, python-3.x

is there any way to get one value from some attribute in json and modify it  and assign it to some other attribute in same json file ?

I have tried

```
{"total":5,
    "ospf":
     {
     "start":1,
     "stop":5
     },
 "isis":
     {
         "start":${total}, ==> expecting 5
         "stop":${total}+10 ==> expecting 15 
         }
 }
```

something like this

```
'value' : {
            'x' = 10
            }
    'calculate' : {
        'total' = Value[x]*2
        }

    data = json.load(fileobj)

expected : data['calculate']['total] => 20  ##x*2
```

Comment: JSON is just an exchange format. Once parsed into Python it is *just a bunch of dictionaries and lists*. Just load, update and dump again.

Comment: What is the whole JSON-like dump before the `json.load()` supposed to signify? It is certainly not valid JSON data. JSON does not have any support for dynamic data descriptions.

Comment: whatever i mentioned is example only, exact thing is i have some attribute as x = 5, i want to use through out the json file by increment it as per requirement. so, JSON doesn't support dynamic data descriptions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
in_json = '{"x": 10}'
data = json.loads(in_json)
data['calculate'] = {'total': data['x']*2}
out_json = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: i am looking for values to be changed dynamically within JSON, without handling outside the JSON